# Top command with ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm new with ansible and I am trying to execute the following ad-hoc command:

```
ansible group -i inventory -m shell -a "top"
```

With the following error:

```
top: failed tty get
```

Are there any way to execute **top** with ansible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

top by default runs in interactive mode and periodically updates the values, So ansible can't get the ternimal output, May be you can use "top -b -n 1" as shown below.

```
ansible group -i inventory -m command -a "top -b -n 1"
```

meaning of -b and -n for 'top' is below:

```
   -b  :Batch-mode operation
        Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful for sending output from top to other programs or  to  a  file.   In  this
        mode, top will not accept input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the `-n' command-line option or until
        killed.
   -n  :Number-of-iterations limit as:  -n number
        Specifies the maximum number of iterations, or frames, top should produce before ending.
```

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"Is there any way to execute top with ansible?"*

A: Yes. It is possible to run *top* in batch-mode

```
-b  :Batch-mode operation
    Starts top in Batch mode, which could be useful for sending output from
    top to other programs or to a file.  In this mode, top will not accept 
    input and runs until the iterations limit you've set with the `-n' 
    command-line option or until killed.
```

For example

```
$ ansible group -i inventory -m command -a "top -bn 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Top command has batch mode to run for scripting or any command line programs. Kindly run below command in ansible with shell module.

```
 top -bco +%CPU -n1
```

For More info like: listing disk,ram,cpu,current connection list in ansible run below playbook accordingly.

```
- name: Server utilization report in ansible
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:
          - name: Disk Report
            command: df -h /opt /
            register: disk
          - debug:
                  var: disk.stdout_lines
          - name: Memory report
            command: free -wh
            register: ram
          - debug:
                  var: ram.stdout_lines
          - name: CPU counts
            setup:
                 filter: ansible_processor_vcpus
            register: core
          - debug:
                   var: core.stdout_lines    
          - name: server load
            command: uptime
            register: load
          - debug:
                  var: load.stdout_lines
          - name: top
#           command: top -cbn1
            shell: top -bco +%CPU -n1|head -n22
            register: process
          - debug:
                  var: process.stdout_lines
          - name: current network connections
            shell: ((netstat -antup  |grep -i proto )2> /dev/null; sudo netstat -antup | grep -i esta) 2> /dev/null
            register: network
          - debug:
                  var: network.stdout_lines
```